# Xcode successfully builds but fails to run macOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, cloudkit, osx-gatekeeper

I've written a mac application that uses CloudKit, and ever since I've upgraded to Sierra and XCode 8, the app will successfully build, but Xcode will not launch the application when I click "run".

If I go into the Derived Data folder and manually double-click my application to launch it, it crashes immediately and displays the following in the error report:

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 12000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1
```

What's interesting is, if I archive the app and export a Developer ID-signed application, the exported build is signed successfully and works perfectly.

Additionally, If I go into the capabilities tab and toggle off the iCloud capability, the app successfully runs in XCode.

Whenever I run spctl on the app in the DerivedData folder, whether or not I have iCloud enabled or disabled, I always get this:

```
spctl --assess --verbose=4 MyApp.app
MyApp.app: rejected
```

In the General tab on XCode I've set it to "Automatically manage signing", and as far as I can tell, all of my certificates are valid.

Not really sure what to do here. I've even tried disabling Gatekeeper completely and still no luck.

Comment: I am having the same problem with an objective c application. Tried automatically manage signing, manually managing signing. Tried renewing provisioning profiles, changing the iCloud preferences on provisioning profiles. Also tried deleting the relevant folder from the Derived Data folder, all with no effect. FWIW I can run the app from the profiler.

Comment: Asked apple support. They said the problem was that the app is using an ad-hoc provisioning profile, and so entitlements with com.apple.developer won't work. You could check in terminal with    codesign -dv /MyAppname.app  I successfully got it to run by archiving it and running from the exported file, but nothing I have done seems to change it from the ad-hoc profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aaaargh. Found the answer to my problem, I hope the answer may help you as well.
My code signing was set up correctly in the development target, but it was *ad hoc signed* in the Test Target. As soon as I set up a profile for the Test target the problem went away.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that was it *facepalm*. Funny, when I tried running the project on another machine with Sierra it gave me an actual error message (codesign utility exited with 1). Even when I signed the tests they still failed for me, but by going into "Edit Scheme" and unchecking all of the tests from "Build", my app runs again. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me!  Thank you very much -- been struggling with this for hours.