# Latest macOS version 10.15.4 claims code signing is not valid at customer

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, provisioning-profile, lazarus

Okay, so I have am using codesigning and (verified) notarization for my macOS desktop application.

I also test my own downloads on macOS 10.15.3 by downloading and executing. (If for instance I forget to code sign, then I can not run my executables)

But now I have a customer using macOS 10.15.4 and he sent a screenshot showing following error:

> Exception Type: EXC_Crach (Coode Signature Invalid)
>
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Excpetion Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Reason: Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1

Here are relevant parts of how I sign

```
  codesign --force --options runtime --timestamp --entitlements "/Volumes/DiskW/projects-cool/myapp/osx/shrents/casc-dlv.plist" --sign "Example" "/Volumes/DiskW/projects-cool/myapp/osx/finaldist/myapp.app"

  codesign --display --entitlements :- "/Volumes/DiskW/projects-cool/myapp/osx/finaldist/myapp.app"

  /usr/bin/xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.example.myapp" -u "info@example.com" -p "xxx" -t osx -f "/Volumes/DiskW/projects-cool/myapp/osx/finaldist/myapp.zip"

  /usr/bin/xcrun altool --notarization-info yyyy -u "info@example.com" -p "xxx"

  /usr/bin/xcrun stapler staple -v "/Volumes/DiskW/projects-cool/myapp/osx/finaldist/myapp.app"
```

Contents of casc-dlv.plist:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Contents of Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>MA</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.example.MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>a1wse</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>10.1.4</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>10.1.4</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>MyApp.icns</string>
    <key>CSResourcesFileMapped</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance</key>
    <true/>             
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>       
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>*</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fold</string>
                <string>disk</string>
                <string>****</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.8</string>       
</dict>
</plist>
```

Checking my "keychain" in macOS I have:

- "Developer ID Application: Example (xyz)"

(nothing else of relevance)

...

Looking at: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list

I only have expired profiles I used many years ago for developing apps

Comment: You're not using xcode as an ide but you have it installed and are using components of it, right?

Comment: Yes. I posting my commandline in a few seconds

Comment: Can you create a virtual machine running 10.15.4 and reproduce the customer's error? If so, then try dropping the entitlements and stapling. You don't have to have entitlements (or a truly functional app) to test for codesigning. You don't have to staple if you and your customer have internet access.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39927501/1707353) yet? Maybe it has nothing to do with the customer using a newer OS version.

Comment: I have not had any other reports ever about this problem for the past many years. Always code signed like above (notarization relatively new though)  -- however the link is interesting. However, I do not use XCode IDE... And I do not believe that i my problem but I will double check later today and expand this question with more info

Comment: If you adhoc code sign, which has nothing to do with the IDE, then maybe adhoc code signed apps on 10.15.3 are "ok" but not on 10.15.4. The reason I'm hanging with you on this one is that I might have the same problem next week with my app.

Comment: Hmmm... I have no idea how to see/check if I am adhoc code signing my macOS software when using command line, but I will try Google. I have checked my keychain (nothing but certificate) and online developer profile (all old mobile app expired profiles)

Comment: [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/288291/247075) might be a good start for reading. However, I think my earlier advice about entitlements might be a good area to start testing. Create different versions of the app with different (or none) entitlements until one of them can be opened in a (or the) reproducible environment.

Comment: Removing entitlements /  casc-dlv.plist appears to solve the problem. I think there must be bug somewhere... At least I do not believe I am using adhoc... Not sure if to post this as an answer?

Comment: At this point, you'll want to focus on Apple-specific communities like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and [this](https://developer.apple.com). Good luck, pardner.

Answer (score 0):

Removing entitlements / casc-dlv.plist appears to solve the problem.

It is an answer since it solves the problem, but I will not mark this answer as the correct one since in many cases simply dumping entitlements is not always possible.